# Clarity on caching?

Tags: caching

Drupal 8 uses Opcache, while most people still use APC for Drupal 7. I am not sure what I should use for a Drupal 7 site, as there is no Opcache module for Drupal 7. There is the [OPcache](https://www.drupal.org/project/opcache) module, but I don't think that will do the trick as it is a development module.

Which of the two options should be used for Drupal 7 when I use at least PHP 5.5, which supports OpCache?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drupal 8 recommend using [Zend OpCache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php) (a PHP extension), which is enabled at server side, and it caches PHP code; it is not used for caching data.
For data caching, Drupal 8 automatically uses APCu without requiring third-party modules, if the PHP extension is enabled. See [Several cache bins now use APCu caching by default](https://www.drupal.org/node/2327507), which states:

> In order to improve cache performance, Drupal 8 now has:
>
> - A cache.backend.apcu service that site administrators can assign as the backend of a cache bin via `$settings['cache']` in settings.php for sites running on a single server, with a PHP installation that has APCu enabled, and that do not use Drush or other command line scripts.
> - A cache.backend.chainedfast service that combines APCu availability detection, APCu front caching, and cross-server/cross-process consistency management via chaining to a secondary backend (either the database or whatever is configured for `$settings['cache']['default'])`.
> - A default_backend service tag (the value of which can be set to a backend service name, such as cache.backend.chainedfast) that module developers can assign to cache bin services to identify bins that are good candidates for specialized cache backends.
> - The above tag assigned to the cache.bootstrap, cache.config, and cache.discovery bin services.
>
> **This means that by default (on a site with nothing set for `$settings['cache']` in settings.php), the bootstrap, config, and discovery cache bins automatically benefit from APCu caching if APCu is available**, and this is compatible with Drush usage (e.g., Drush can be used to clear caches and the web process receives that cache clear) and multi-server deployments.

So, if you are using APCu as data cache on Drupal 7 (which require installing a third-party module), keep using it; when you will port the site to Drupal 8, you will not need anymore a third-party module, to use APCu to cache data. That is why the [APC - Alternative PHP Cache](https://www.drupal.org/project/apc) module doesn't have a Drupal 8 version.

The module you are linking just allows Drupal to report status information about the cache and reset the cache; it is not a module you need to use *Zend OpCache* with Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

Its more related to php versions than drupal itself, Drupal tries to gain benefits of new php features [opcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php) that has been added to php itself starting from version 5.5.

> PHP in version 5.5 comes with a caching engine built-in – OpCache – which stores precompiled script bytecode in the memory.

APC does the same plus gives you the ability to store user data for previous php versions.

> APC cache won’t work with the newest PHP versions. It doesn’t support PHP 5.5 at all

Read that article for more information [understanding opcache](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-opcache/)